# Same kotlin code in different projects running in different ways android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, position, android-recyclerview

i was working with two projects. Same code in both the projects running very different ways.
here is my code explained

(Project 1)
in RecylerView Adapter , in bindview holder when running code it printing all the position at one time , does not matter how much

(project 2)
positions are printing according to their scroll , which is i think correct

///here is what i have tried .......

"project 2" have kotlin version (ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41') , so i updated my kotlin version of "project 2" to 1.3.30 to 1.3.41.

"project 2 was made with androidX" so i migrated my "project 1" to androidX

updated my whole project, cleaned multiple time, rebuild the project, re-imported the project but nothing works

i have to apply pagination and this needs to print position according to their scroll. But problen is that , since all the position are printing at one time so it keeps on loading next to the next page continuously in "project 1"

//here is my adapter

```
class All_Blogs_adapter(
val mylist: ArrayList<Model_class_one>,
val fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity,
val pages: Int,
val api: String ) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<All_Blogs_adapter.Viewholder>() {
var n_page = 2

inner class Viewholder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun mydata(list: Model_class_one, posit: Int) {

    ///here my positions are printing
        Log.i("scrollposition", " my >>$posit")
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): Viewholder {
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(fragmentActivity).inflate(R.layout.allplayer_adp_admin, parent, false)
    return Viewholder(layout)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mylist.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Viewholder, position: Int) {
    val Values = mylist[position]
    Log.d("running", "in bind holder $position")
    holder.mydata(Values, position)
}
}
```

///here is my build.gradle

////Project 1

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.sekhontech.nextcricketscoring'
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 6
    versionName '1.5'
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'

implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

///// build.gradle (project)

```
 buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
} 
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

////Project 2

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  android {
      compileSdkVersion 28
      defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.sekhontech.ncricketonline'
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 4
    versionName '1.3'
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

  dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

//// build grade(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
 }
 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

This might be the bug of project , but how to clear project bug. How can I resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what the problem was..

i had added my recylerview in nestedscrollview and set nested scroll enable to false.. which loading my all the items at one time. so always check and then use nestedscroll for recyclerview

Comment: In general, this will always happen if you use `wrap_content` for your RecyclerView size